# Post values from Wordpress Metabox to custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata, meta-tags

I was wondering if there is anyway of posting vales from a wordpress metabox and adding it to a custom non hierarchical taxonomy (tags).

Here is the code for the custom taxonomy

```
// Custom taxonomy for Ingredients
register_taxonomy(  
   'ingredients',  
   'mysite_tax',  
    array(  
        'hierarchical' => false,  
        'label' => 'Ingredients',  
        'query_var' => true,  
        'rewrite' => true  
    )  
);
```

I am currently using the wpalchemy metabox and the code for the metabox is

```
<div class="my_meta_control">

    <h4>Ingredients</h4>

    <?php while($mb->have_fields_and_multi('recipe_ingredients')): ?>
    <?php $mb->the_group_open(); ?>

        <?php $mb->the_field('quantity'); ?>
        <label>Quantity and Ingredients</label>
        <p><input type="text" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" value="<?php $mb->the_value(); ?>"/></p>

        <?php $mb->the_field('ingredients'); ?>
        <p><input type="text" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" value="<?php $mb->the_value(); ?>"/></p>

        <?php $selected = ' selected="selected"'; ?>

        <br/><?php $metabox->the_field('units',1); ?>
        <select name="<?php $metabox->the_name(); ?>">
        <option value="unit"<?php if ($metabox->get_the_value() == 'unit') echo $selected; ?>>--Select Unit--</option>
                    <option value="Test"<?php if ($metabox->get_the_value() == 'Test') echo $selected; ?>>Test</option>
                    <option value="Test2"<?php if ($metabox->get_the_value() == 'Test2') echo $selected; ?>>Test 2</option>
                    <option value="Test3"<?php if ($metabox->get_the_value() == 'Test3') echo $selected; ?>>Test 3</option>
        </select>

        <a href="#" class="dodelete button">Remove Document</a>
        </p>

    <?php $mb->the_group_close(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <p style="margin-bottom:15px; padding-top:5px;"><a href="#" class="docopy-ingredients button">Add Document</a></p>
    <br /><p><a style="float:right; margin:0 10px;" href="#" class="dodelete-ingredients button">Remove All</a></p>

</div>
```

I want to pass the values in the ingredient field only to the custom taxonomy. I'm a php novice, so it may as well be quite easy and I don't realise it :)

I can get the values in the page template using this code

```
<?php
                                    // loop a set of field groups
                                    while($ingredients_metabox->have_fields('recipe_ingredients'))
                                    {
                                        echo '<li>';
                                        $ingredients_metabox->the_value('quantity');

                                        $ingredients_metabox->the_value('ingredients');

                                        $ingredients_metabox->the_value('units');
                                        echo '</li>';
                                    }
                                ?>
```

However i was wondering if there is a way to push the values(just ingredients) into the custom taxonomy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use a save_filter, although I wonder whether WPAlchemy is the way to go. The time spent learning WPAlchemy could be spent learning the core WordPress API and PHP, which will be much more useful over the long term. That said, if you do choose to stick with WPAlchemy, below is how one would implement a *save_filter*.

```
<?php

    $foo_meta_box = new WPAlchemy_MetaBox(array(
        'id' => '_custom_meta',
        'title' => 'My Custom Meta',
        'template' => TEMPLATEPATH . '/custom/meta.php',
        'save_filter' => 'foo_alchemy_save_filter'
    ));

    function foo_alchemy_save_filter($meta, $post_id) {
        unset($meta['ingredients']; // remove ingredients meta data before saving
        // do your custom taxonomy stuff using taxonomy API such as wp_set_object_terms() 
        return $meta;
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

See this [WPAlchemy](http://farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/#comment-3941) comment and some of the comments following it.

Comment: Hello, glad to see your site is back up and running :). I have been taking a look at those comments over the weekend and it seems like they want to do the opposite of what i want to do. It seems like they want to get terms from a custom taxonomy and pull it into a metabox. I want to push terms from a particular field in the metabox to a custom taxonomy. Also I can't save_action function right, it keeps breaking my site.

Answer (score 0):

you can see http://farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/#comment-3941 for more idea it consists of some good arguments under the topic you really need !